# how to pass a dynamic value from input field to progress prop of vue-circle component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue-circle to display the skill and the level of the skill of a user passing throw v-modal of an input field to the vue-circle component but i keep getting this error when i enter a value of 80:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "progress". Expected Number with value 80, got String with value "80".
```

this how i'm passing the values:

```
<vue-circle
      v-for="(skill, index) in skills"
      :key="index"
      :progress= "skill.level"
      :size="130"
      :reverse="false"
      line-cap="round"
      :fill="fill"
      empty-fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)"
      :animation-start-value="0.0"
      :start-angle="0"
      insert-mode="append"
      :thickness="12"
      :show-percent="false"
    >
     <span>{{ skill.skillName }}</span>
</vue-circle>
```

and this the input where i enter the data:

```
<div class="form-row" v-for="(skill, i) in skills" :key="i">
     <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                <label for="skill">skill</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="skill"
                placeholder="Skill"
                v-model.lazy="skill.skillName"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
              <label for="languageLevel">Level</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                pattern="\d*"
                minlength="2"
                maxlength="3"
                class="form-control"
                id="skillLevel"
                placeholder="Skill Level"
                v-model="skill.level"
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the input type="number", the problem is type="text" is returning but a string **progress** prob takes but a number. or you can still use the parseInt(string, radix) method to convert the value to a number

Comment: when you did that you still recieved but this error [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "progress". Expected Number with value 80, got String with value "80".?

Comment: i didn't understand you